# Check if station is locked using Mac Bash Script Command

Tags: macos, bash

I was also looking for a bash method to test if user has locked the station.

This topic here shows that we can test if screen saver is active or not with bash:
[Check if Screensaver is Active using Mac Bash Script Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841417/check-if-screensaver-is-active-using-mac-bash-script-command/2983536)

I found this but this is also for screensaver: [How can I detect if the screen is locked or screensaver is active from the Terminal in OS X 10.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390123/how-can-i-detect-if-the-screen-is-locked-or-screensaver-is-active-from-the-termi/1391162)

Anyway to use bash to test if station is locked or not?

Thanks

Comment: If bash isn't a deal breaker, it's possible [using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505255/osx-check-if-the-screen-is-locked).

Comment: Thanks @Fugue I won't mind and would defnitely appreciate it can you please share it.

Comment: @Fugue oh i saw that topic and did a javascript ctypes port of it, that has its issues so was looking for a a bash method.